# Generator no console output

Tags: python

I am trying to follow a [tutorial on Python coroutines](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf).
The sample code is as follow:

```
import time

def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2)      # Go to the end of the file
    while True:
         line = thefile.readline()
         if not line:
             time.sleep(0.1)    # Sleep briefly
             continue
         yield line

# Example use
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logfile = open("my-file")
    for line in follow(logfile):
        print(line)
```

This is supposed to be an implementation of Unix `tail-f` which reads a file line by line from the end.

However running this produces no output in the console, except for a blinking cursor.

Any suggestions on why its not printing the lines of the file ?

Comment: Is the file getting updated after you start running this?

Comment: no its a static file

Comment: In a separate window, try `echo hello >> my-file` (note the double `>`). The word `hello` should then appear in the Python window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script prints only data that is appended to the file. If you have any pre-existing data or text in the file, it won't be returned by the function `follow(thefile)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is always `sleep`ing and executing `continue` as after you seek to the end of the file with `thefile.seek(0,2)` there will simply be *nothing to read*.

And as you're doing that in a loop that never ends (`while True:`), you never reach `yield line` and loop forever without any output.

Comment: He is trying to emulate `tail -f`. There will, eventually, be something to read if an external process subsequently writes to the file, extending its end.

Comment: @Robᵩ, but the behavior shown in the question was because there was nothing to print, that's the problem

Comment: "*there was nothing to print*" -- yep, that's the problem. Not that his code is incorrect, but that his test is incorrect. When something to print is supplied, his code works flawlessly. Your answer seems to imply that OP's solution lies is modifying his code.